# Benchmarking Elasticache with memslap

Tags: memcached, benchmarking, performance, amazon-elasticache

I am benchmarking Elasticache m2.4xlarge instance running in Amazon AWS cloud using memslap.

memslap is run from a m2.4xlarge Amazon EC2 linux instance. Memslap successfully works with concurrency levels 256, 512 but fails when the concurrency level is  1024.

When I run memslap with concurrency = 1024, I get the following error
*getaddrinfo(): Name or service not known
Initialization failed*

**How do I tune the EC2 instance to get memslap to work with a higher concurrency level (>1024) ?**

*ulimit output is unlimited and sysctl -p shows 'fs.file-max = 300000'*

-Santhosh